# Get neighbourhoods around given location

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I can get to know the suburb using google maps api. I use Autocomplete `getPlace()` to get `sublocality_level_1`. I want to know the nearby sublocalities as well.

I tried nearbysearch with `type="sublocality"`. That fetches only maximum two results per call. Fetch with radius 200m returns two sublocalities and fetch with radius 500m returns two other sublocalities.

I want to get all sublocalities around given `place_id` for given radius (say 5000m). Is there a way to get that?

Comment: Have you tried reproducing the query in a circle (say 5000m in radius) around your point of interest (probably don't want more than 10 points, but  watch for OVER_QUERY_LIMIT status being returned).

Comment: i tried with 5000m radius. That did not help. Doesnt work for sublocalities. Tried radarsearch as well. But, unable to filter out by type sublocalities there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like Google Places API doesn't have support for getting the nearby suburbs. You can only get point of interests like Restaurants, Fuel Stations, etc. 
You can you the `getPlace()` Google Places API autocomplete to get the latitude and longitude of your suburb, and use the geonames.org API for fetching the nearby suburbs/sub localities. You have the options to pass `lat`, `lng` and `radius`.

Here is a example GET for fetching suburbs near 13.041703, 80.251943 in 5 KM radius

http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPlaceNameJSON?lat=13.041703&lng=80.251943&radius=5&username=demo